# How do I open my garage door without a remote from outside?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

1993 Craftsman garage door opener; my wife must have put something up against the garage door keypad and inadvertently triggered the vacation mode button - now we're locked out.

The remote control is disabled; none of the buttons work. Checked the batteries - they're fine. Tried tripping the breaker; no change.

The problem is, the garage has no door (just the garage door) and just 2 small windows that we could fit through if i broke the glass.

Is there any way to disable the vacation mode from a remote control?

I'd really rather not break the glass for obvious reasons. If i have to do something like that, i'll cut a hole in the wall, get in, open the garage and put a door where i cut the hole.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like the controller needs to be reset and the remotes reprogrammed.  Usually this requires physical access to the opener, but if you have a hardwired remote it might be possible to pair it via the keypad. Check the manual for your opener.

But back to the problem of how to open it. If the garage does not have an alternative access there should be a manual cable release which disconnects the door from the opener chain so that you can manually open it.  Often this is in the form of a small key near your garage door.  With the key you can open the lock and pull the manual release.

[image: Manual cable release]
<sub>(source: [garage-door-automation.co.uk](http://www.garage-door-automation.co.uk/images/accessory/apl0430_small.gif))</sub>

If the installation was done correctly, you have one of these you just need to find it.  If you don't have the key a locksmith should be able to open it for you.

If you do not have a manual release then I think you will have to resort to breaking a window.

Comment: Thats it. as soon as i saw the picture, i remember my wife pulling out a lock on the garage door this morning and a steel wire being attached to it. I pulled it all the way out, the track latch released, opened the garage and held the lock button for 3 seconds. Sure enough, it opened. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy of Youtube...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMz1tXBVT1s

Just gotta find an old wire-framed coathanger!

Answer (score -1):

To open a Craftsman Garage Door opener, simply purchase a new outside keypad, when you prepare the keypad enitially the door will open. They cost $50.00 but are well worth the money.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The keypad only works if you know the security code, and then it only works if the unit is in vacation mode. So, two reasons why this wouldn't help the original poster.