# How can I open my garage door from the outside with a dead opener?

Tags: doors, garage

This morning I found myself locked out of my garage. My interior wall opener isn't working and neither is the remote. The light on the interior pad is out, suggesting a loss of power. Unfortunately, my fuse box is inside the garage, and I I have no way of entering unless I can disable the opener and manually open the door. How in the world can I do that?

Comment: Is there a window in the garage door itself? If not is there a blank section of interior house wall that abuts an interior wall in the garage and which has nothing on it on the garage side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open my garage door without a remote from outside?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15921/how-do-i-open-my-garage-door-without-a-remote-from-outside)

Comment: no window, but yes, a blank interior wall abutting interior garage wall

Answer (score 4):

Some models include a lock cylinder on the garagedoor. Typically it is in the top panel. Insert the key (hopefully you have it) and the lock should come out when turned. A length of cord will be attached to the back of the lock. Pulling the cord releases the door from the opener and allows it to be opened manually.

Comment: If your door doesn't have one of these I would install one when you you get the door open.

Comment: I did look for that keyhole when I read some other problem-solving tips, but I don't have one

Answer (score 3):

Ok, Solved the problem. There are 4 bolts on the outside of the garage door, holding the opening mechanism to the door. I undid them and the coupling holding the opening mechanism to the door let go, and I was able to manually open the door. The culprit? I was sure the breaker couldn't be the problem, because everything else electrical in the house was working fine. When I looked at the box I immediately saw the flipped breaker...and the only circuit on it was the garage door. What caused the circuit to break on the garage door after 13 years, I'll never know...

Comment: I'm surprised you were able to remove those bolts from the outside, but glad you got in. I'd suggest installing an external manual release with a key and then replacing the bolts with something more secure.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a *release handle* inside, near where the door is attached to the raising mechanism.  It often has a wooden or plastic toggle handle. Pull it and the door will be freed from the raising trolley, and will then be able to be lifted manually on its rails.

Comment: Anita indicated they have no access inside of the garage, so they need a way to pull this from outside.

Comment: I (foolishly) assumed there was an inside access and thought she couldn't figure out how to get her *car* in and out. A more careful reading would have clarified.

Comment: yes, I can't get in at all. There is a 3-4 inch give on the left side of the garage door when I pull it; nothing gives on the right. Is possible to break the door free with sheer physical strength...not mine hahaha

Answer (score 1):

I found this youtube video that helped me in the same situation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXuifg1x_-Y

I was able to use this video for exactly the same purpose, so thank you for this! I was locked out of my garage for days due to a power outage.

The video describes that there is a seal at the top of the garage where one, if one were so inclined, could shove a coat hanger, shim, or slim Jim into it to attempt to trigger the manual release in order to move the door up and down manually. The device would have to be slid under the seal, and then shimmied around until the hanger or curved edge could either wrap around the metal bar to pull it towards the door, thus triggering the manual release (only works in some models), or it would need to wrap around the handle of the manual release. Either way, force could then be applied by pulling outwards and downwards to trigger the release.

Comment: Hey, Ryan, welcome to the site.  Your post pulled this old thread to the main page and I immediately thought of that before seeing the video, so the idea is great.  The problem with just a link is that links rot over time and if that's all there is, the answer ends up having no value.  Videos also aren't great as the only source of information because some people may have problems viewing them, and the information can't be indexed to help someone search for a solution.  Can you add the essential information for the solution to the answer?  Use the link for attribution and reference.  Thanks.

Comment: Concur - please briefly describe what that video shows..  Welcome to Home improvement.  Please take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.